# Prohibit dropping items into the same TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I got another JavaFX problem. To keep the story of the problem very short:

I have two TableViews with items that I want to drag and drop in the respective TableView. The problem that I'm encountering at the momemt is that I can drop the item in the same TableView where I got it from. That should not be the case and I want to prevent this.

Is there a way to restrict the target table and, if so, what do I have to do?

Thanks a lot for your help!

implemented setOnDragOver method:

```
selectedParticipantsTable.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            // data is dragged over the target 
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();

                if (db.hasContent(participantsDataFormat)){    

                    if(selectedParticipantsTableData.contains(db.getContent(participantsDataFormat)) != true){
                        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.NONE);
                    }
                }
            event.consume();
        }
    });
```

Ok, I think I got a bit further. I created an own DataFormat to put the items in the ClipBoard of the DragBoard. The problem now is that the SimpleStringProperties in the MetaData class are not serializable and I don't know how to this properly as I always get an EOFExceptio when I drag the item over the other TableView.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably need to show some code to show how you are implementing the drag, but the basic idea is that you can check if the item is in the current table view in the dragOver handler, and only accept the drag if it is not.

Comment: I mostly copy&pasted the code that I found through google to enable the drag&drop function, but I barely understand tbh.

I thought about checking if the item is already in the ObservableList of the tableview, the problem is, I don't know how to get the current dragged item. All I see is that the item is converted into one string but my Meta Data for the items are two seperated SimpleStringProperties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction that you can only put serializable objects onto a dragboard is a real pain. Even if you make your model class serializable (which is difficult, because JavaFX properties are not serializable, but not impossible), it's probably not going to do what you want, as you will get a copy of the object on dragging instead of a reference to the original object.

The only workaround I have is essentially to store the dragged object in an instance variable (if the code for dropping is in a different class to the code for dragging, then you need something more convoluted).

Here is an SSCCE using the usual contact table from the Oracle tutorial:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TwoTablesDragging extends Application {

    private static final String DRAGGING_PERSON_KEY = "dragging-person";
    private Person currentDraggedPerson ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Person> contacts = createPersonTable();
        TableView<Person> selectedContacts = createPersonTable();
        contacts.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );
        HBox root = new HBox(10, contacts, selectedContacts);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void setUpDragAndDrop(TableView<Person> table) {

        // note: It's generally better to set drag detected on the table rows, using
        // a rowFactory, so you don't rely on selection. This is just a "quick and dirty"
        // approach for a demo
        table.setOnDragDetected(e -> {
            Dragboard db = table.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString(DRAGGING_PERSON_KEY);
            db.setContent(content);
            currentDraggedPerson = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        });

        table.setOnDragOver(e -> {
            Dragboard db = e.getDragboard();
            if (DRAGGING_PERSON_KEY.equals(db.getString()) &&
                    ! table.getItems().contains(currentDraggedPerson)) {
                e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
            }
        });

        table.setOnDragDropped(e -> {
            Dragboard db = e.getDragboard();
            if (DRAGGING_PERSON_KEY.equals(db.getString())) {
                table.getItems().add(currentDraggedPerson);
                e.setDropCompleted(true);
            } else {
                e.setDropCompleted(false);
            }
        });

        table.setOnDragDone(e -> {
            if (e.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.MOVE) {
                table.getItems().remove(currentDraggedPerson);
                currentDraggedPerson = null ;
            }
        });
    }

    private TableView<Person> createPersonTable() {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(column("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty, 100));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty, 100));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Email", Person::emailProperty, 175));
        setUpDragAndDrop(table);
        return table ;
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> prop, double width) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> prop.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        col.setPrefWidth(width);
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Person {
        private StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setLastName(lastName);
            setEmail(email);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFirstName(final java.lang.String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLastName(final java.lang.String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }

        public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getEmail() {
            return this.emailProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setEmail(final java.lang.String email) {
            this.emailProperty().set(email);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I got a SimpleIntegerProperty (sorry, forgot to mention this) in the MetaData, which represents a unique ID of the object, wouldn't it be sufficient just to make use of the contains method in the ObservableList of the TableView? I just want to make sure that there isn't the same object (not reference-wise but semantic-wise) in the Table multiple times. No need to copy the object with the exact same reference.

Comment: That would work, if you are using the unique ID as the semantic definition of equals in the objects `equals` method. But when you drop the object, you presumably need to get the "whole object" - this gives you a convenient way to do that too.

Comment: I edited the code above with the if-statement to check whether there is such an object or not but it doesn't let me drop any item into the table. No matter if it's empty or not it's just showing me the symbol that it's I'm not allowed to drop anything...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the lambda expression and moreover i have to use java 7. What comes instead of the 'e ->' expression if i want to have suitable java7 code? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Just convert the lambdas to anonymous inner classes.

Comment: Are there currently any known bugs/problem with macs (mac os) using this solution when drag&dropping items?

I got 3 colleagues with macs trying to use this solution, while one is not having any problems on mac os 10.10.3 yosemite and the other two not able to drop the dragged item in the other table (using 10.10.3 and 10.10.4 yosemite). Neither any exceptions nor any response from the system, there's literally nothing happening when they are trying it.

Comment: I haven't tried on OS 10.10; I have 10.9.5 and it works fine on there (also only tried with a trackpad; I don't use a regular mouse any more). I would put some logging in the handlers and see where it stops working. Also, you said you were using Java 7; do you see the same issues if you test it with Java 8? (Is Java 7 even supported on Yosemite?)